# Justifying exchange of integration order

Tags: complex-analysis

I am tasked with using Morera's theorem to demonstrate that $f(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin zt}{t}\ dt$ is entire.

The general approach I want to take is to simply to show that for $\Gamma$ being the boundary of any rectangle whose sides are parallel to the axes in $\Bbb C$,

$$\int_\Gamma \int_0^1 \frac{\sin zt}{t}\ dt dz = \int_0^1 \int_\Gamma \frac{\sin zt}{t}\ dz dt.$$

Then, we can show that $\frac{\sin zt}{t}$ is analytic w/r.t. $z$, so the inner integral is zero, and hence the whole shebang is zero.

Indeed, this approach is taken by the author.

However, I am having difficulty justifying the exchange of order of integration. I know that it must be done by showing that the first integral (or the second) converges, but I'm just not sure how to show that.

Comment: It should follow from the fact that you have a bounded integrand on bounded paths of integration. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Alternate_theorem_statement

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks. I've been pushed in Fubini's direction (actually, it was my first idea, but unfortunately, I know nothing of measure theory.)

Comment: This is a good excuse to learn a little measure theory then ... but I know such a process is not quick. The sound-bite version is that exchange of integration in this situation should be "easy". But "easy" depends on your background. What tools for exchanging integration (or limits in general) are expected to be known by you and other students in your course?

Comment: The expectation is that we should be able to use Fubini. But the prerequisite courses don't necessarily cover that material. I believe all that would be needed is uniform convergence, or am I mistaken?

Comment: What is converging here, whose convergence might be uniform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be less about mathematics and more about how to negotiate with a professor regarding which facts can be used. One possibility is to clearly state what you are using:

> **Special case of Fubini's theorem.** When $a,b,c,d$ are finite and $f$ is jointly continuous in both variables, we have 
>   $$\int_a^b \int_c^d f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_c^d \int_a^b  f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Then apply this to each side of rectangle $\Gamma$ separately. Integral over a line segment in the complex plane is readily written as an integral over  a closed interval in $\mathbb R$,

---

Alternative approach, without Morera's theorem: write 
$$\frac{\sin tz}{t}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} t^{2n-2} \frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$
and observe that as long as $z$ is bounded ($|z|\le M$) the series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. 
Therefore, it can be integrated term by term, which yields a power series representation for the integral.

Comment: The problem actually is two parts. The first says, essentially, "use Morera's theorem," while the second says, "use a power series."

Both approaches are fairly easy, and actually, the textbook includes solutions for both. The part that I had issues with was invoking Fubini -- I wasn't sure whether it was germane for the course, and in either case I wasn't up to snuff on how to properly use it. I appreciate the clarifications, though!

Comment: I guess that the connection I am missing is the link between "$f$ jointly continuous" and "$[a,b], [c,d]$ being $\sigma$-finite measure spaces." But if I muddle through the definition of a $\sigma$-finite measure space, it becomes clear...ish.

Comment: @Arkamis There is no direct link. (1) you do not need to muddle through the definition of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, because the spaces here have *finite measure*. (2) The assumption of continuity is convenient here because it takes care of two things at once. Being continuous on a compact set, $f$ is both bounded and jointly measurable (yeah that's a hard one), and since the measure of the product set is finite, $f$ is integrable. // But my point is that since you are not going to prove Fubini's theorem, you can just state a special case and justify the solution with it.

Comment: Alright, I see. So continuity on the compact set gets me to the special case; if I wanted, I could show that these conditions are enough to get me to Fubini's theorem generally, but that's unnecessary.